# How to scroll to a specific table row in PySimpleGUI

Tags: pysimplegui

I have a table that has more rows than fit on the screen (ie rows > num_brows).

Is there an API to scroll to specific row visible .

Selecting the row via

```
window["table"].Update(select_rows = [99])
```

selects the row, but does not scroll until the row becomes vsiisible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that on the TK widget:

```
window["table"].Widget.see(99)
```